# Testing REST API, Bulk API limits

Tags: rest-api, api, soap-api, limits, bulk-api

I am working on a scenario where I export a set of records to Salesforce via bulk API 2.0, I need to handle the daily Salesforce limit exceeded scenarios gracefully.Mainly the REST and Bulk V2 API limits.

- Is there a document on what kind of errors and error codes Salesforce returns when limits are reached? (sounds like a googlable point, but could not find any official resource)
- After implementing the logic to handle the above limits, is there any way I can test this functionality apart from intentionally exceeding the limits on the org? - The org is shared and I cannot afford to consume all the APIs myself.

Comment: You could create your own scratch org to test?

Answer (score 0):

Once you exceed a specific rolling limit, you'll receive a HTTP 403 response code with the errorCode "[REQUEST_LIMIT_EXCEEDED](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/errorcodes.htm)" in the return payload. There is no built-in mechanism to test this functionality other than configuring your API consumer so it handles 403 return codes with that message appropriately.

One resource you can take advantage of is the [Limits API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.228.0.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_limits.htm), which will provide a payload describing your current organization's limit consumption status.